# Take off namespace from Jaxb fields

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I want to know how to type only one time namespace in jabx, because in every fields i need to put the namespace.

The code below show it.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "nfeProc", namespace = "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class NFeProc {

    @XmlElement(name = "NFe", namespace = "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe")
    private NFe nfe;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "versao")
    private String versao;

    public NFe getNfe() {
        return nfe;
    }

    public void setNfe(NFe nfe) {
        this.nfe = nfe;
    }

    public String getVersao() {
        return versao;
    }

    public void setVersao(String versao) {
        this.versao = versao;
    }

}
```

I just wanna to put one time.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it at the package level using the `@XmlSchema` annotation.  By setting element form default to be qualified, all elements without a namespace specified via an annotation will belong to the given namespace.

**package-info.java**

```
@XmlSchema(
    namespace = "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe",
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Comment: i don´t see this annotation...it´s native from java?

I found this solution from your blog, it´s very good...
I want to know about the ns0, ns1....
Here i don´t need to use?

Comment: @Here is `@XmlSchema`  in is included in the JDK/JRE since Java SE 6.  When the namespace is specified in `@XmlSchema` JAXB implementations normally leverage the default namespace.  If you are interested in controlling the prefix the following will help:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/11/jaxb-and-namespace-prefixes.html

Comment: I create one package in Eclipse, and assigned the option to create package-info.java, so i put the code showed below, and take off all references using namespaces and the code run so fine...

thanks